# How to switch between Docker Containers using the same service name?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, makefile, dockerfile

I have two Dockerfiles for the foo service: foo-dev and foo-debug. There are only 3 lines of differences between these files where foo-debug installs delve allowing me to debug the docker container for golang. I use the make commands to send the correct dockerfile to docker compose. It works as expected but there is a quirk. Switching between the containers of debug and dev is cumbersome where I need to stop the container, kill it, and rebuild the other one by passing --build to docker compose, then I can run the make command. Is there a better strategy? Provided simplified code snippets below

Makefile

```
compose-dev:
    DOCKER_FILE=foo-dev.Dockerfile docker compose up -d

compose-debug: 
    DOCKER_FILE=foo-debug.Dockerfile docker compose up -d
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services: 
  foo: 
    build: 
      context: . 
      dockerfile: ${DOCKER_FILE}
```

foo-dev.Dockerfile -> foo-debug.Dockerfile (diff shown below)

```
FROM golang:1.20.8-bullseye as builder
+ RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go install -ldflags "-s -w -extldflags '-static'" github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest

FROM debian:bullseye-slim COPY --from=builder /go/bin/foo ./bin/foo
+ COPY --from=builder /go/bin/dlv ./bin/dlv
+ CMD [ "./bin/dlv", "--listen=:4001", "--headless=true", "--log=true", "--accept-multiclient", "--api-version=2", "exec", "./bin/foo"]
- CMD ["./bin/foo", "-debug"]
```

I know Docker Compose offers [profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/); however, this would result in duplicated code where the docker-compose.yml would contain both a foo-dev service and foo-debug to differentiate them but with the same duplicated sub configuration.

Comment: What if you add an image block with a dynamic tag. That way you don't have to keep rebuilding and overwritten the image compose builds when you switch. You just have a separate tag for each version

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem to simplify the process of switching between development and debug modes without duplicating your Docker Compose configurations or Dockerfiles excessively, consider the following strategies:

**Use Argument in Dockerfile:**

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM golang:1.20.8-bullseye as builder
ARG MODE
RUN if [ "$MODE" = "debug" ] ; then CGO_ENABLED=0 go install -ldflags "-s -w -extldflags '-static'" github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest ; fi

FROM debian:bullseye-slim
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/foo ./bin/foo
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/dlv ./bin/dlv
CMD if [ "$MODE" = "debug" ] ; then exec ./bin/dlv --listen=:4001 --headless=true --log=true --accept-multiclient --api-version=2 exec ./bin/foo; else exec ./bin/foo -debug; fi
```

Now, you just need to pass the build argument in your Docker Compose file:

```
version: '3'
services: 
  foo: 
    build: 
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile 
      args: 
        MODE: ${MODE}
```

**Utilize Makefile for Mode Setting:**

In your Makefile, you can set the MODE environment variable which will be picked up by Docker Compose:

```
compose-dev:
    MODE=development docker compose up -d

compose-debug: 
    MODE=debug docker compose up -d
```

This setup means you only maintain one Dockerfile and one Docker Compose configuration. You toggle between the modes using the **MODE** argument.

**Reducing Rebuild Time:**

To avoid complete rebuilds when switching between modes, make sure that the steps that are common between the two modes (like copying code, installing dependencies) are kept at the top of the Dockerfile, and only the diverging steps (like installing Delve) are under the conditional block. This way, Docker can utilize its caching mechanism efficiently.

**Cleanup:**

```
clean:
    docker compose down
```

Now you can switch between modes with just make compose-dev or make compose-debug, and when you want to clean up, just run make clean. This setup reduces the manual steps involved and keeps your configuration DRY by avoiding duplication.

Comment: ARG is build time and CMD is evaluated at runtime; therefore, the arg is not available. You can copy the arg into an env making it available at runtime but docker discourages CMD logic.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand quiet to ur question, but what ur goal is, to make ur workflow faster without boilerplate + without more typing ?

If u hate the switching process, where you need to stop, kill, run correct file. You can create some function at makefile and do chain calls.

```bash
dcdown:
 @docker-compose down
dcstop:
 @docker-compose stop
dcrerun-dev: dcstop dcdown
 @DOCKER_FILE=foo-dev.Dockerfile docker compose up -d
dcrerun-debug: dcstop dcdown
 @DOCKER_FILE=foo-debug.Dockerfile docker compose up -d
```

my point is that how u made ur own func for passing docker arg, you can do that with other bash stuffs.

btw. whats wrong with running both of containers ? i mean if you have HW, then docker/containerd is pretty lightweight container runtime engine.

Comment: This won't work as you expect because it will use the cached container. You would still need to pass the --build flag when bringing up docker compose. So far, the best I can find is using docker profiles with the downside of repeating a large block of the configuration between the dev and debug flow. I did need to add both profiles to make stop but that was minor